# Why they are called to-be verbs?

Tags: verbs

Being non-native speaker and English being 2nd language, I always stumble upon discrete thoughts about English grammar.

I don't know, how obvious this question is to native speaker, but I wonder:

> Why "are", "is", "were" "am" etc. are called **to-be** verbs?

What's **to-be** about them? My concern is, why they are called **to-be** verbs and not just verbs? I don't understand the word **"to-be"**.

I would appreciate, if you can explain me with fundamental thought behind it.

Comment: All of those forms are inflections of the verb "to be". The form of "be" must change for tense and for the number (singular/plural) of the  subject. I am, you are, it is, they are, they were. That means that they are all the same verb, changed according to context.

Comment: I don't understand most basic thing. What is TO BE?

Comment: You used a form of "to be"  in your sentence: "is". Did you understand it? "To be" is the infinitive form of the same verb.

Comment: I am not asking about "are", "is" etc. I am asking what is TO BE, I don't understand. E.g. mango, banana, etc. are fruits, but what is fruit- I don't know that. In same manner, I don't understand what TO BE ...what is grammar sense of TO BE.

Comment: Have you looked at a dictionary? Search for the word "be".

Comment: https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/be

Comment: Yes Sir, it says- **Exist.**

Comment: It says a lot more than that.

Comment: They are not called "to be verbs". There is one verb, the infinitive form is: be. I am, you are, he/she/it is, we are, you are, they are. That is the present simple of the verb **be**. Do you conjugate verbs in your language? In English, be is the most irregular of all the verbs.

Answer (score 5):

### Inflection

In English, verbs have multiple forms, so - for example - there's **have**, **has**, **had**, **having**, all of which belong to the verb **to have**.

### Infinitive

Verbs are conventionally cited or named by their infinitive forms.  The infinitive form may include a preceding "to", or it may be a bare infinitive (without "to").  The form in the dictionary usually excludes the preceding "to".  The form used to cite the verb when discussing it often includes the "to".

### To be

The verb **to be** is irregular, and has the present tense forms **am** (as in *I am*), **are** (as in *you are*, *we are*, *they are*), and **is** (*he/she/it is*), along with the past tense forms **was** (as in *I was*, *he/she/it was*) and **were** (as in *you were*, *we were*, *they were*). The past participle is **been**, present participle **being**.

Etymologically, the different forms of this verb come from multiple roots.

If you look up [be](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/be_1?q=be) in the Oxford Advanced Learner's Dictionary, it has a list of "verb forms" that you can expand.  You can also read about the verb "to be" [here](https://learnenglish.britishcouncil.org/english-grammar-reference/the-verb-be).

### Examples of *be* as an infinitive

Here are some examples of *be* in its infinitive form:

- *I want **to be** a star.*
- *We could **be** friends.*
- *It might **be** too late.*
- *I don't want **to be** abandoned.*
- *It's nice **to be** here.*

**Imperative.** As pointed out by Lambie, **be** is also used as the imperative form, e.g. *Be quiet* or *Please be kind*.

Comment: Sorry, for asking a naive question. But, can you please tell me that when we use "be" in its true form? We use inflection of "be", but when do we use "be" in  a sentence. Can you update your answer for that? It will really help me.

Comment: @Cicada OK, I've added this info.

Comment: @Cicada **Be a nice person** and reread the answer. :) There is no such thing as using be in its true form. You asked about to be and that is what you got. Otherwise, **be** is an imperative. Be safe. (people say all the time nowadays)

Answer (score 5):

Most verbs have several different forms: Regular verbs, for example have a basic form "play", a past tense form "played" (which is identical to a past particple form), a form used in the third person singular "plays" and a present participle/gerund form "playing"  We might say "play/played/played/plays/playing"

Irregular verbs have irregular patterns like "eat/ate/eaten/eats/eating". You have to learn these individually

Some verbs are very irregular:  "go/went/gone/goes/going".  That odd "went" is because the past tense of another verb "wend" with similar meaning to "go" replaced the orginal past tense of "go".  Now we don't think of go/went as two different verbs.  We think of "went" as the past tense of go.  The verbs "go/went" mean the same (with different tense).

The verb  "be" is particularly complicated. What was originally three different verbs with similar meanings have become mixed up, and now act as if it is one irregular verb.

The present of "be" is "am/are/is".  The past tense is "was/were" the part participle is "been", the present particple is "being".  We consider all these to be different forms of the same verb. They are all different forms of "be"

The words "am/is/are/was/were/been/being/be" all mean the same.

Now in any language that has words that can change form, there is one form that is the "dictionary form"

For example, in English, nouns have a singlar "cat" and plural "cats".  But the dictionary will only list "cat".  Irregular words like "man/men" might have an entry for "men" that says "plural of man".

The dictionary form of a verb in English is the bare infinitive. In nearly all verbs the bare infinitive is the same as the first person singualar... with one exception:  "be".  This is why we call  am/is/was  "be-verbs".  The basic dictionary form of the word is "be"

In a sentence you use "be" where ever an infinitive is required:

> I want *to sing* a song.
> I want *to be* happy.

or a bare infinitive

> You can *eat* the ice cream.
> You can *be* good.

Comment: Sorry, for asking a naive question. But, can you please tell me that when we use "be" in its true form? We use inflection of "be", but when do we use "be" in  a sentence. Can you update your answer for that? It will really help me.

Comment: It is the infinitive.  It is used like other infinitives, as "to be" or after modals "can be" or "will be" (and so on)

Comment: @Cicada "Anna and Oscar will **be** [arrive] at the gym at 10 pm.  They will **be** wearing their exercise clothes.  If their car is not running they both will **be** late."

Answer (score 2):

BE SAFE
BE GOOD
BE NICE
And maybe the virus won't get you.

And above all, **be** yourself.

*be*=imperative form of the verb and the infinitive form.

They are not called "to be verbs". There is one verb, the infinitive form is: *to be*.
The rest of the forms are the present: *I am*, *you are*, *he/she/it is*, *we are*, *you are*, and *they are*.

past and future tenses: *was/were* and *have/had been* and *will be*.

All of this irregularity is still referred to as **the verb “be”**.

The simple past of the verb *be* is: I was.
The past perfect of the verb *be* is: I have been
etc.

It has many tenses and forms. So, one verb, many tenses and forms.

Comment: Yeah! thank you for the additional information. +1

Answer (score 1):

“are", "is", "were" "am" etc. are different *inflections* of the verb “to be”.

We normally *refer to* verbs by their infinitive (not inflected) form. Since the bare infinitive (“be”) could be confused with one or more of the inflected forms, we specifically use the to-infinitive (“to be”).

“to be” is the most irregular verb in the English language, and it is also the most commonly used. (Those facts are probably connected.) As a result, teachers will spend a lot of time discussing just this one verb. It’s possible that your teacher used “to be” as an exception for that reason but the bare infinitive for all other (much simpler) verbs, which would explain your confusion.

Answer (score -1):

No one really answered the question of why it is called "to-be" but rather they answer it on very technical terms when he said that he is not a native speaker.
I am also wondering if Native speakers do know the origin "to be"...

I am also wondering why it is called "to be"...

so here's my personal theory "be", according to the dictionary means "exist" with "to" on it means "to exist".

ergo, it is called "to be" verbs because it is meant to exist or could be existing, or about to exist. "to be" is somewhat a word that links sentences and or phrases that is:

1. About to happen. (She "is" going to jump.)
2. Already happened. (They "are" cursed by the witch.")
3. It is currently happening. (I "am" eating.)

imagine without the "be" verbs...

I hope this makes sense why it is called "to be"